# Problem with numpy array viewer in PyCharm 2020.1

Tags: python, pycharm, numpy-ndarray

In the recent update for PyCharm CE 2020.1, they've botched up the numpy array viewer. To be specific, I'm unable to increase the size of the viewer window, vertically. It shows just 4 rows at a time, even when there is ample space. Please see the pic below:

[image: botched pic]

Is there any quick fix for this? That will greatly help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a regression in 2020.1 - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-41601

The fix is ready and is in testing right now, should be included in 2020.1.1 minor update.

Answer (score 0):

I think that gray color rectangle is a scrollbar

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I know that. But I would like to have 10 rows visible at a time, atleast. You see the gray space below Resize Automatically checkbox... I want it to be used... It used to be that way in 2019.3, but with 2020.1 it has been botched up!